# Object equality

Tags: c#, clr

[Object base class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs) has the following code which compares equality of two objects

```
public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB) 
    {
        if (objA==objB) {
            return true;
        } 
        if (objA==null || objB==null) {
            return false; 
        } 
        return objA.Equals(objB);
    }
```

What is the difference between comparisons `objA==objB` and `objA.Equals(objB)` and why do we need to check `objA==objB` separately?

UPDATE: The comment in the source code says that "`Equality is defined as object equality for reference types and bitwise equality for value types`". Thus if we deal with reference type and `objA!=objB` then we must return `false` without other comparisons, don't we? `objA.Equals(objB)` looks redundant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first comparison is a simple reference identity comparison - in other words, do the values of `objA` and `objB` refer to the same object (or are both null). This has two purposes in `Equals(object, object)`:

- It's an optimization so that when we compare an object with itself, we don't need to actually call `Equals`
- This makes `Equals(null, null)` return true without having to have a special case for it

`objA.Equals(objB)` calls the virtual [`object.Equals(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which can be overridden in subclasses. (An `Equals` implementation typically starts off with the same reference comparison as we've already performed, again for optimization purposes... it's a bit of a shame to have the same comparison twice, but it makes sense to avoid a virtual call when we don't need it.)

For example, `string` overrides `Equals` so that two independent `string` objects can still be equal to each other. (`string` also *overloads* the `==` operator to have the same meaning as `Equals`, but that's irrelevant in the `Equals(object, object)` code, as overloading is a compile-time matter... the `==` in `Equals(object, object)` will only *ever* perform a reference comparison.)

EDIT: The comment about "Equality is defined as object equality for reference types and bitwise equality for value types" is the *default* implementation of `Equals` (that's where the comment occurs). It has nothing to do with `==`, and that behaviour can be overridden by overriding `Equals` further.

Comment: please check my update to the question

Comment: @Ask: See my edit, at the bottom. You say "the comment", but that comment applies to the method *above* the one that you posted.

Answer (score 3):

`objA==objB` checks for the reference equality where as `objA.Equals(objB)` can be overridden. So when references are equal then obviously we don't need to call `Equals` method which may perform value equality.

It is not necessary to compare for reference equality, I'd say it is an *optimization*, since value equality can be overridden and it may be **expensive** implementation which they(BCL team) wanted to optimize away when they know both are same references.

So this simply works on the fact that if references are equal then their values are also equal.

Answer (score 1):

`==` checks for reference equality. All types can override `Equals` method, so the purpose of calling `objA.Equals(objB)` is to compare objects based on custom implementation if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

The instance `Equals()` method is virtual and can be overridden in derived classes.